# Using Visual Basic to Make Average Test Score Generator in C#

Tags: c#, average, calculator

I'm trying to create a calculator for an assignment that takes three integer inputs and takes the average and returns that to user. I'm using Visual Basic (it is required) to make the GUI. I'm having trouble with two things, first, I cannot get the aVer to divide by 3 because it is not a integer and second, I do not know how to get an output with the average in the last textbox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string userInfo1;
    private string userInfo2;
    private string userInfo3;
    private string aVer;
    private string num1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int aVer = 0;
        aVer = Int32.Parse(userInfo1 + userInfo2 + userInfo3);

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userInfo1 = 0;
        userInfo1 = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userInfo2 = 0;
        userInfo2 = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userInfo3 = 0;
        userInfo3 = Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text);
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = Int32.Parse(aVer);
        MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
    }   

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: just as a side note, your question title doesn't make much sense.  You mention that you had to use Visual Basic to design the form, but the code you presented is completely C# code, and the problem you are experiencing is based on how C# works, so the Form being Visual Basic isn't relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to phrase it correctly. I meant to say I'm using the Visual Studio, not Visual Basic, to make the GUI and the code behind it is C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring your variables multiple times.  The variables inside the function calls will hide the variables you have defined outside in the class declaration, and the class variables will never be set to a value.

It doesn't appear that you are ever using any of the variables in their string form, so all the `private string` declarations should be changed to `private int` declarations.  This also makes the `int userInfo1 = 0;` declarations unnecessary.  Having them actually breaks the ability to see the values in the `button1_Click` function.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me clean up a lot!